# How can I write this query without using subqueries?

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Reltab(id,tid) VALUES
      ((SELECT id FROM BlogDetails WHERE Title = '$title'),
      (SELECT tid FROM TagTable WHERE tname = '$words[$i]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using parameters for such a query.  Then, you can use a `join`:

```
INSERT INTO Reltab (id, tid)
    SELECT bd.id, tt.tid
    FROM BlogDetails bd JOIN
         TagTable tt
         ON bd.Title = ? AND tt.tname = ?;
```